# ActiveRecord STI: How can I break out of the parent class' default scope

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1, sti, default-scope

On Rails 3.1 RC6, given

```
class Animal < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope where(legs: 4)
end
```

The following does not work as expected:

```
class Man < Animal
  default_scope unscoped.where(legs: 2)
end
```

The resulting SQL statement looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM animals WHERE legs = 4 AND legs = 2
```

How can I override the parent class' default scope entirely?

I've also tried the followings none of which work:

```
default_scope{ unscoped.where legs: 2 }
default_scope with_exclusive_scope{ legs: 2 }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I dug into Rails' source code and came up with a solution that works under Rails 3.1 (tested with activerecord 3.1.0.rc6):

```
class Animal < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope where(legs: 4)
end

class Man < Animal
  self.default_scopes = []
  default_scope where(legs: 2)
end
```

Comment: Seems that this works in Rails 3.0:  self.default_scoping = []

Answer (score 0):

I'd found this and it helped me http://m.onkey.org/default-scopes-and-inheritance-to-the-rescue

Comment: This link is broken. Do you know where it might have moved to?